# WPF Bind ControlTemplate's content to Property in Control?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, wpf-controls

I want to bind Border.Background in my Button ControlTemplate to the Background Property of my  button. Usually I would use a TemplateBinding:

```
  <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ColuredButton">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
                               <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                            </Border> 
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

But I get the error: "Cannot set TemplateBinding if not in a Template".. But I am in a Template! (It works if I dont use LinearGradientBrush and bind the borders Backround Property directly to {TemplateBinding Background}....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Snowbear said, you should bind `Color` to `Color` and not `Color` to `Brush`.  But in his  solution, `TemplateBinding` with deep property `Path` such as `Foreground.Color` isnt allowed as part of the binding markup.

So use the following...

```
    <Border.Background>
      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
         <GradientStop Color="{Binding Foreground.Color,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                       Offset="0.2"/>
         <GradientStop Color="{Binding Background.Color,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                       Offset="0.6"/>
      </LinearGradientBrush>
   </Border.Background>
```

And it should work.

Comment: I had a control that uses a template within a template, and I had to do this binding in both of them.  Worked like magic!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have some other error here, but it is not reported well. `GradientStop` accepts a `Color` in its corresponding property while `Background` and `Foreground` properties of a `Button` are brushes, not colors. If you think that `Background` and `Foreground` will be `SolidColorBrush` you might try accessing their `Color` property in your binding, but I'm not sure whether it will work or not:

```
<GradientStop Color="{TemplateBinding Foreground.Color}"/>
```